# How to put a select into an integer with POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to put this  request (S`ELECT qte FROM table_stock where id_pro = cpt1`) into an integer, like that i will be able to check if the product still exist (if quantity >0) so I us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT qte 
   into quantite 
FROM table_stock 
where id_pro = cpt1;
```

More details in the [PL/pgSQL reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid the loop with a single query like insert into table_result select... where quantity > 0;